# Jenkins2, managing configuration by puppet, credentials

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'd like to manage Jenkins 2 configuration by puppet.
I've copied configuration from deployed manually instance, and templated it.

But I've got problem with hashed passwords in configuration. When I'm putting old hash (from previous instance) jenkins is overwritting it, and password does not work. For example:

```
<managerDN><%= scope['ldap_bind_dn'] %></managerDN>
<managerPasswordSecret><%= scope['ldap_bind_pw'] %></managerPasswordSecret>
```

I've got BIND `password` and `dn` stored in hiera, and when I'm putting it from hiera and restart Jenkins, config is rewritten and new value does not work.

```
-        <managerPasswordSecret>{HASH_FROM_HIERA=}</managerPasswordSecret>
+        <managerPasswordSecret>{NEW_NOT_WORKING_HASH=}</managerPasswordSecret>
```

I cannot figure out how to manage this credentials in a way Jenkins will accept them?

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution, just instead of hash, puppet should place `plain-text` and jenkins automatically will replace it with proper hash value